# Accessing dynamic struct vector through struct vector in the for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

This is how my struct looks like and for loop which is inside "main" and I'm trying to run:

```
struct cave{

    cave(std::string name, bool is_small, bool is_visited)
    :name{name}, is_small{is_small}, is_visited{is_visited}  {}
    
    std::string name{};
    std::vector<cave*>connections;
    bool is_small{};
    bool is_visited{};
    
};

cave* find_cave(std::vector<cave*> &v, std::string s){
    
    for (int i{}; i<v.size(); i++){
        if (v[i]->name==s) return v[i];
    }
    
    return v[0];
}

//v_temp contains some strings
std::vector<std::string> v_temp;
std::vector<cave*> vec_2d;

for(int i=0; i<v_temp.size();i++){
    vec_2d.push_back(new cave(v_temp[i],islower(v_temp[i][0]),0));  
}

/*
adding connections so pointers to other "caves" runs also in for loop
vec_2d_temp is has size 2 and contains string values.
*/
vec_2d[i]->connections.push_back(find_cave(vec_2d,vec_2d_temp[1]));
//or
vec_2d[i]->connections.push_back(find_cave(vec_2d,vec_2d_temp[0]));

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec_2d.size(); i++) {
    if (vec_2d[i]->connections.size() < 2) {
        std::cout << "TEST: "<<vec_2d[i]->connections[0]->is_small << "\n";
    }
}
```

What I'm getting here sounds "Access violation reading location 0x00000000".
When I change just for test i to 0 for vec_2d it runs fine:

```
std::cout << "TEST: "<<vec_2d[0]->connections[0]->is_small << "\n";
```

Am I running something out of scope here?

Comment: _"dynamic struct vector"_ ? You have a `vector` of pointers. and you've stored a `nullptr` in it which you dereference. Either don't store `nullptr`s in it - or check if it's a `nullptr` before dereferencing it. `if (vec_2d[i]->connections.size() < 2)` should probably be `if (not vec_2d[i]->connections.empty())`

Comment: `vec_2d[i]->connections.size() < 2` can mean `vec_2d[i]->connections.size() == 0`, so `vec_2d[1]->connections[0]` could be an access violation.

Comment: Btw, what is `vec_2d`? Please show a [mre].

Comment: The code you posted could be correct. The error is probably somewhere in the code you didn't post. Don't make the mistake of thinking that where a program crashes is where the error is.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::vector<cave*> vec_2d;` and please see edited post if it's enough.

Comment: Use [this](https://godbolt.org/z/E39YT7fP1) and make it compile (and produce the same kind of error you get) - then copy what you've got and put that in the question.

Comment: @Nelfeal correct I should check if `vec_2d[i]->connections.size() == 1` for my purpose, many thanks!

Comment: @Jacob If you actually need help, the put a [mre] in the question so that we can compile it and reproduce the problem.